# How to retrieve data from MariaDB where any dates are in the format YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: sql, date, select, mariadb, date-formatting

I'm retrieving data from MariaDB using:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

Three columns in this data contain dates (and are formatted as dates in the form YYYY-MM-DD). When I receive them on the client side, they appear as "2021-07-11T14:00:00.000Z" but I instead want "2021-07-11". I've tried lots of things, including:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name DATE_FORMAT(date_column_one,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

which doesn't work, as well as

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_column_one,'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM table_name
```

but this simply adds another column of data - I still get the other dates in the wrong format.

There is a lot of info about this stuff online but I can't find anywhere where they actually combine the formatting of dates with a basic select statement.

Comment: What is the actual _type_ of `date_column_one` ?  Is it a date column, or maybe a text column?

Comment: The datatype is set to date

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `DATE_FORMAT` is not using the format mask you seem to want here, which is `yyyy-mm-dd`.  Try using the correct mask, and also don't select the date columns via `SELECT *`:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...  -- excluding date_column_one etc. 
       DATE_FORMAT(date_column_one, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS date_column_one
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return a `date`, then you can use the `date` function:

```
SELECT . . .,  -- the other columns
       DATE(date_column_one)
FROM table_name;
```

However, this returns a column with the type of `date` and you are at the mercy of your application to display it.  Some applications might do you the "favor" of deciding that you want to see the time and timezone.

You can control this by converting the value to a *string* using `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT . . .,  -- the other columns
       DATE_FORMAT(date_column_one, '%d/%m/%Y')
FROM table_name;
```

Now the value is a string and its format will not be changed.  The format `'%Y-%m-%d'` is the standard YYYY-MM-DD format, and I much prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to use the STRFTIME abbreviations you can find them all here

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.